# How to append nested key-value to json array in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

My `json` values in jsonb column are below:

```
{"Id": "7324326", "UserName":"Henry", "Details": {"Email":"henry@test.com", "Phone":"03722", "Images": ["https://face.png"]}}

{"Id": "325325", "UserName":"Mark", "Details": {"Email":"mark@test.com", "Phone":"83272", "Images": ["https://hair.png", "https://nose.png"]}}

{"Id": "832743", "UserName":"David", "Details": {"Email":"david@test.com", "Phone":"65128", "Images": []}}
```

I have nested key - `"Images"` that has array of strings. How to write query that will add to `Images` new keys/values `("UploadedBy":null and "Size":null)` and transform array of string to key-value `("https://face.png" -> "Link":"https://face.png")` like below:

```
{"Id": "7324326", "UserName":"Henry", "Details": {"Email":"henry@test.com", "Phone":"03722", "Images": [{"Link":"https://face.png", "UploadedBy":null, "Size":null}]}}

{"Id": "325325", "UserName":"Mark", "Details": {"Email":"mark@test.com", "Phone":"83272", "Images": [{"Link":"https://hair.png", "UploadedBy":null, "Size":null}, {"Link":"https://nose.png", "UploadedBy":null, "Size":null}]}}

{"Id": "832743", "UserName":"David", "Details": {"Email":"david@test.com", "Phone":"65128", "Images": []}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_set`:

```
update tbl set js = jsonb_set(js, '{Details,Images}'::text[], 
    coalesce((select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('Link', v.value, 'UploadedBy', null, 'Size', null)) 
     from jsonb_array_elements(js -> 'Details' -> 'Images') v), '[]'::jsonb))
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=72f865cb458c5b1ec8f4cf4c96e36cbf).